# Terminal emulator with bookmarks/history of commands/directories?

Tags: terminal, bookmarks

I work a lot with the command line (GNOME Terminal + Bash).
I would love to have an easy/graphical way to use
[bookmarks|history] of [commands|directories].

For example, I would like to have a list of the last 20 commands, and just click on one of them to execute it again. Or I would save 10 bookmarks of frequently used working directories and change to one of them by a mouse-click.

I don't see any easy possibility for that.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It's quite hard. From my opinion for this purposes are better make own aliases for frequent commands and directories. It's simple and portable if you need it on other linux machine, because you only copy aliases from ~/.profile (on different distros it's named different) to next profile file.

Or use some of alternative terminal emulators which have some added features. For example [Final Term](http://finalterm.org/) is interesting (smart completion or sematic menus). It's not exactly what you search, but it can be useful. ;-)